# Kotlin: Why is the textView still unchanged after I selected the button?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Kotlin: Why is the textView still unchanged after I selected the button?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcpED.png)

MainActivity.kt:

```
if(radioButton_male.isChecked){
    textView_maleOrFemale.text = "You are male!"
}else if(radioButton_female.isChecked){
    textView_maleOrFemale.text = "You are female!"
}
```

Comment: Impossible to say from that code snippet alone. We don't know when you run that code, or on which thread.

Comment: Did you implement `onClick` for these radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

method `onCreate` calling only once when Activity started.
if you want to dynamically change the text you should use `Observer Pattern = Listener`

There should be code like this :

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            textView_maleOrFemale.text = if (isChecked) "You are male!" else "You are female!"     
}
```